# How do I find my Staff of Magnus in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find a lost item?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37365/how-can-i-find-a-lost-item)

I've been asked to close a rupture and need my Staff of Magnus to do this. Thing is, I don't know where I've kept it. I've lived in the Dawnstar sanctuary and checked there, but its not there. I live in the College of Winterhold where I'm Arch Mage, and checked there. But it's not there either.

I had this staff with me when I had to close that big thingy in the Hall. Now I don't remember where I stored it.

Is there any way to find out where I left it? Some console command or something like that?

Comment: if you have access to the console, you can just give yourself a new one

Comment: @spartacus Finding the one I had is not possible? No console command to take you to where it's at? I tried player.moveto, but it wont work.

Comment: @Normal player.moveto only works on npcs, there's no console command to locate an item afaik.  And its entirely possible the staff has been garbage collected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Staff of Magnus is a quest item during the Mages' Guild questline, but after that it's just another staff.  It's possible you sold it, dropped it, or stuck it somewhere you'll never find it.

You could always give yourself a new one with the console command:

> player.additem  00035369 1

Alternatively, you could just skip the staff altogether.  I believe you're playing the "[Aftershock](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Aftershock)" radiant quest that pops up after the guild questline is over.  The staff is not required for these quests - despite what you're told when you accept it.  In my game, I stumbled upon the rupture without ever being told there were any, and closed it with my standard equipment.  The UESP has a note confirming this.  Just kill the magic anomalies by whatever method works best for you, and you'll be just fine.

Comment: Related question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42310/aftershock-radiant-quest-how-does-the-staff-of-magnus-fit-in-does-it-have-a